# nodejs firebase-admin sdk: Can I remove Database folder if I'm only using VerifyIdToken?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm trying to implement jwt verification process on server side, unfortunately the backend service allows nodejs packages that are less than 5 mb size.
If we check the size of **nodejs firebase-admin sdk** is about 6,9 mb, the database folder alone is 6mb,
so I'm wondering if I can remove that folder if I'm only using

```
admin = require('firebase-admin')// idToken comes from the client app
admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `@firebase/database` will be fine as long as you don't call `admin.database()` anywhere in your code. Although I suspect you can get things down to under 5MB that way. You will likely have to remove Firestore, Storage and some of their dependencies like GAX as well.

```
$ npm install firebase-admin --production
$ du -sh node_modules/
35M node_modules/
$ du -a node_modules | sort -n -r | head -n 10
72496   node_modules
15016   node_modules/@firebase
13056   node_modules/@firebase/database
13032   node_modules/@firebase/database/dist
8512    node_modules/protobufjs
7184    node_modules/@google-cloud
6288    node_modules/es-abstract
5352    node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore
5152    node_modules/google-gax
5112    node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build
```

Comment: correct, but I'm not sure if they count the sum of all dependencies along with the main module, or they make sure that every one of them is less than 5 mb

Answer (score 0):

I just used 3rd party library which is [jwt-simple](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-simple) and used the decode function like this:

```
jwt = require('jwt-simple')
jwt.decode(token, private_key, 'RS256')
```

**private_key** is a string you get from firebase console, and **token** is the one provided by user (check https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#node.js)